# Prefer jagged arrays over multidimensional

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I get this performance issue from visual studio ([Prefer jagged arrays over multidimensional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182277.aspx)).
The code to be replaced is "//matrix".
How can i do this with my code?

```
      public static int LevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
    {
        int n = s.Length; //length of s
        int m = t.Length; //length of t

        int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1]; // matrix

        int cost; // cost
        // Step 1
        if (n == 0) return m;
        if (m == 0) return n;
        // Step 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++) ;
        for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++) ;
        // Step 3
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            //Step 4
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                // Step 5
                cost = (t.Substring(j - 1, 1) == s.Substring(i - 1, 1) ? 0 : 1);
                // Step 6
                d[i, j] = System.Math.Min(System.Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                          d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
            }
        }
        // Step 7
        return d[n, m];
    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Servy my question is, how can i convert the array to a jagged array.
 "int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];" --> ?

Comment: What research have you done on how to create a jagged array, and what problems have you had implementing the solutions that you found in your research?

Comment: "I get this performance issue" What convinces you that the performance issue has anything to do with representing your data as multi-dimension non-jagged arrays? As far as I can see, this is a non-trivial algorithm, so I would *not* expect the representation to dominate the timing of it.

Comment: If its *actually* a matrix, then you aren't wasting any space by it being a multi-dimensional array. As per the linked documentation, you can suppress the warning in this case. Besides; those rules are just suggestions. They don't indicate an *actual* performance issue.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET A multi-dimensional array isn't always the right data structure when you have a matrix.  A large sparsely populated array is actually better off using another representation that doesn't require explicitly stating all of the zeros.  Given that large sparsely populated matricies actually come up a lot, this can be relevant.

Comment: @Servy Excellent point. I was trying to point out that he may not have a problem at all, as dasblinkenlight also said, and that he may not even be in violation of the rule. Sparse matrices are certainly better represented by a different data structure.

Comment: In this very specific case, you can implement Levenshtein distance with 2 one dimensional arrays (see [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), Iterative with two matrix rows) rather than a two-dimensional array. That cuts the space requirement from n*m to n+m and you don't need to use a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @Servy: This matrix doesn't look sparse.  Every `d[i, j]` is written to.

Comment: `t.Substring(j - 1, 1) == s.Substring(i - 1, 1)` can be sped up a LOT.  `t[j-1] == s[i-1]` does the same thing by directly comparing characters, without creating garbage strings.

Comment: @BenVoigt My point was that it's simply a consideration that should be made, not necessarily that this particular matrix is populated so sparsely that it shouldn't be a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version which uses only a single dimensional array.

```
public static int LevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
{
    int n = s.Length; //length of s
    int m = t.Length; //length of t

    int stride = m+1;
    int[] d = new int[(n + 1)*stride];
    // note, d[i*m + i + j] holds (i,j)

    int cost;
    // Step 1
    if (n == 0) return m;
    if (m == 0) return n;
    // Step 2, adjusted to skip (0,0)
    for (int i = 0, k = stride; k < d.Length; k += stride) d[k] = ++i;
    for (int j = 1; j < stride; ++j) d[j] = j;
    // Step 3
    int newrow = stride * 2;
    char si = s[0];
    for (int i=0, j=0, k = stride + 1; k < d.Length; ++k)
    {
        // don't overwrite d[i,0]
        if (k == newrow) {
            newrow += stride;
            j=0;
            si=s[++i];
            continue;
        }

        // Step 5
        cost = (t[j] == si ? 0 : 1);

        // Step 6
        d[k] = System.Math.Min(System.Math.Min(
             d[k-stride] + 1, /* up one row */
             d[k-1] + 1       /* left one */   ),
             d[k-stride-1] + cost /* diagonal */ );
    }

    // Step 7
    return d[d.Length-1];
}
```

This should improve performance 3 ways:

- No string comparison and no one-character string garbage for the GC to clean up
- Changed memory layout to match iteration order, improving cache behavior
- Used single dimensional array and optimizer-friendly idioms, which should reduce bounds-checking

However, I'm pretty sure that applying mike z's suggestion of using two vectors will make for even clearer code.

Comment: Some of these changes are motivated by http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr.aspx